# freeradius docker Ignoring request to auth address when build through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, freeradius

I am using `freeradius docker` for `AAA` server authentication. For integration tests I am using docker-compose which contains `freeradius` and other services also. When I build, it creates the containers and test the authentication and after that stops the containers.

From one docker container I am sending request to `freeradius` docker container for authentication, which is working fine on my local machine but when I am trying to build through `jenkins`, I am getting

```
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 192.168.96.1 port 36096 proto udp
```

below is my client.conf file -

```
client dockernet {
  ipaddr = x.x.0.0
  secret = testing123
  netmask = 24
  shortname = dockernet
  require_message_authenticator = no
}

client jenkins {
  ipaddr = 192.168.0.0
  secret = testing123
  netmask = 24
  shortname = jenkins
  require_message_authenticator = no
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client subnet/netmask definition is incorrect.

`192.168.0.0/24` will match addresses in the subnet **192.168.0.x** (192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255), but the request is coming from 192.168.**96**.1.

Either change the jenkins client definition to `192.168.96.0` (leaving the netmask as 24), or use `netmask = 16` which will include all addresses from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255.

I would recommend limiting the range to the exact IP, or as small a range as possible, so therefore suggest the former.